# How stable DataContractSerializer XML format is

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm working on WCF HTTP service which will be used by non-WCF compliant clients which raises requests as SOAP XML messages.

I wanted to include custom .NET types in operation contract method signature, custom type like own class Request/Response with few primitive type properties. They nicely serialized by WCF [DataContract serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) so I would provide an sample of XML request/reponse to external client and wanted to document this format as public API request/response format. Is it safe to rely on XML format generated by DataContract serializer or it might change, if so - in which cases/circumstances?

Comment: `wanted to include some custom .NET types` what you means by this ?

Comment: Updated question, basically own types like Request, Response with few properties

Answer (score 0):

WCF’s fundamental communication mechanism is SOAP, WCF-based applications can communicate with other software running in a variety of contexts.

*`Is it safe for external clients to rely on XML format generated by DataContract serializer`*

AFAK  as I know it's safe for the simple reason it's based on  open standard web protocol like

- SOAP for messaging
- WSDL for Metadata
- WS-Security, WS-Trust and WS-SecureConversation for security
- WS-ReliableMessaging for reliability
- WS-Coordination, WS-AtomicTransaction  for transactions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for me it sounds like assuption rather definite statement. I do not want put in architectural decision something not 100% clear, what I'm sure in so could you please slightly more elaborate?